# System update will not download upgraded Kernel - Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a new Project Tango device. When I look into system updates it says there is a new build. When I go to upgrade it gives me a statement saying 
"Couldn't download 501.8mb."

It gives me an option to Retry Download. It doesn't do anything. I have tried 2 different ways to reset. One through the boot load and the other through the system settings.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Tango website here:  https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/tablet

Says:

> The battery must be at least 25% charged to begin the update. We
>   recommend charging the device while the update runs to avoid any
>   interruptions.

Did you check your battery level and confirmed you were charged up enough to start?